# javascript loop overwriting createjs object

Tags: javascript, createjs

I have this code (I've stripped it to the basics)

```
for (var i = 0, len = 26; i < len; i++) {
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);

    var letter_container = new createjs.Container();
    letter_container.chr = chr;

    letter_container.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) { 
        console.log(letter_container.chr);
    });
}
```

So this obviously loops through the alphabet and creates an object for each letter in the alphabet. I want it so that when I mouseover on the container (I have taken out the actual button graphic for clarity) it outputs the character I'm hovering over.

In this case, whichever letter I hover over outputs Z.

How do I make each object unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a couple of words, JavaScript Function Scope...

Each time round the loop `letter_container` gets updated and by the time any `mouseover` events fire `chr` == `Z`.

Best way round this is to wrap the contents of your loop in a function, thus.

```
for (var i = 0, len = 26; i < len; i++) {
    (function(chrCode){
        var chr = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);

        var letter_container = new createjs.Container();
        letter_container.chr = chr;

        letter_container.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) { 
            console.log(letter_container.chr);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

This will preserve the container so that `letter_container` is what you were expecting.